# How do I make Devise verify if the user has an email before try to send a new password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails app where I am using Devise for authentication. Devise lets users click to get an email containing a link to reset their password.

My problem is that the email field is not required in the table "user". There's a login field to authenticate, that is sincronized from another system. I can't set email to required.

I want to verify the email field and return a custom message to the user, if the email is not set. If it is, then Devise will continue and reset the password.

I saw in another post, that I have to override the method "email_required?" in the user model, but I still get the error message "Email cant be blank".

```
def email_required?
  false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user model you should probably have some kind of validation for email like so

```
validates_presence_of :email
```

Also if you wanted to migrate the database to have email as not null it would be like so

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => false
```

Comment: All I have is this:  
`validates :email, length: {maximum: 60}, format: {with: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{1,3})+$/}`

Comment: add this at the end `, :presence => true`

Comment: That's the problem, I can't force the email to be required. If the user doesn't have an email, I have to just show a message, instead of sending the reseted password email.

Comment: That is what validation is for in your reset password email form? maybe you can print out the forms errors e.g `form_for(@reset_password)`  `@reset_password.errors` that is about as far as I will be able to help you without seeing more of your code. Please look at activerecord validations.